# Grouping data using PostgreSQL based on 2 fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with grouping data in postgresql. let say that I have table called `my_table`

```
some_id  | description     | other_id
---------|-----------------|-----------
1        | description-1   |  a
1        | description-2   |  b
2        | description-3   |  a
2        | description-4   |  a
3        | description-5   |  a
3        | description-6   |  b
3        | description-7   |  b
4        | description-8   |  a
4        | description-9   |  a
4        | description-10  |  a
...
```

I would like to group my database based on `some_id` then differentiate which one has same and different `other_id`

I would expecting 2 type of queries: 1 that has same `other_id` and 1 that has different `other_id`

**Expected result**

```
some_id  | description     | other_id
---------|-----------------|-----------
2        | description-3   |  a
2        | description-4   |  a
4        | description-8   |  a
4        | description-9   |  a
4        | description-10  |  a
```

**AND**

```
some_id  | description     | other_id
---------|-----------------|-----------
1        | description-1   |  a
1        | description-2   |  b
3        | description-5   |  a
3        | description-6   |  b
3        | description-7   |  b
```

I am open for suggestion both using sequelize or raw query

thank you

Comment: Your sample data appears to have a problem, because the `some_id = 3` group has one `a` record and 2 `b` records...the `other_id` values are not all the same yet you report it as being such.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ah good catch. thank you. I fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

One approach, using `MIN` and `MAX` as analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(other_id) OVER (PARTITION BY some_id) min_other_id,
              MAX(other_id) OVER (PARTITION BY some_id) max_other_id
    FROM yourTable
)

-- all some_id the same
SELECT some_id, description, other_id
FROM cte
WHERE min_other_id = max_other_id;

-- not all some_id the same
SELECT some_id, description, other_id
FROM cte
WHERE min_other_id <> max_other_id;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using `exists` and `not exists`:

```
-- all same
select t.*
from my_table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from my_table t2
                  where t2.some_id = t.some_id and t2.other_id <> t.other_id
                 );

-- any different

select t.*
from my_table t
where exists (select 1
              from my_table t2
              where t2.some_id = t.some_id and t2.other_id <> t.other_id
             );
```

Note that this ignores `NULL` values.  If you want them treated as a "different" value then use `is distinct from` rather than `<>`.